# How do you create a script to batch add repositories and then batch install packages?

Tags: command-line, apt, synaptic, batch

I've used Synaptic Package Manager to save markings for all installed packages to a file. Here's a snippet:

```
libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil    install
spotify-client  install
mono-2.0-service    install
xtrans-dev      install
inputattach     install
ibus-gtk        install
libappindicator3-1  install
```

spotify-client, though, is not part of the default SPM set of repos. And the script that SPM generated for me doesn't appear to add external sources.

So, how I do I create a script that add external sources, updates the package lists, simulates the installation, and then does an actual batch install?

I assume the programs I've installed through the Ubuntu Software Center are reflected in Synaptic Package Manager--USC is a frontend for a frontend, no?

[image: I want these repos to be added in bulk, via the command line, so that my re-installation will be seamless]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Step 1**

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

> **Step 2**

```
# For example - 
# http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

> **Step 3**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

> **Step 4**

```
PKGLIST="oracle-java7-installer" # Whatever packages you want to bulk install
sudo apt-get install $PKGLIST
```

Comment: Thank you. Am I correct in my supposition that anything I've installed via Ubuntu Software Center is going to be reflected in the Synaptic Package Manager? I'm essentially trying to create my own Ninite-like pain-free installer.

Comment: @PhilVollman Yes, and on the command line. All three tools mentioned (apt-get, synaptic and [Ubuntu Software Center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#Ubuntu_Software_Center_5.4)) are GUIs on top of [apt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) which is a front-end for [dpkg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg).

Comment: Now, my sources.list file doesn't seem to have the ppa.launchpad.net sources; where would I find those?

Comment: @PhilVollman `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: In regards to non-Launchpad-based sources (viz the bottom two sources shown here: http://imgur.com/CfH6wF9) what do I do? I do apologize for being so n00bish. I've been using Ubuntu on-and-off since 2008, but I never seem to learn these things.... >.<

Comment: Examine the text files that end up in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`; they should look almost the same as your screen grab.

Comment: Am doing so. An example file content is "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free"; I'm assuming that's the command I'm going to be inserting into my batch file? Is there anything that needs to be done in addition to that? Again, thank you for bearing with me; I greatly appreciate your doing so.

Comment: That is not a command, that is the file you need to create. For example, `echo "deb repository.spotify.com stable non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13733/discussion-between-phil-vollman-and-elliott-frisch)